# Flyway - drop db, create db

Tags: migration, flyway

I have 2 files: db structure, and db data sql files.
(we are not in part of project where we are creating alter files yet).

Is there a way to achieve running these files before build each time if any of them changed using maven?

The only idea I have is to rename the files (bring the version up) after each change to them making sure flyaway will pick it up.

Is there a smarter way, perhaps using API or some other 'trick'?

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use flyway migrate with the following configuration

```
validationMode=ALL
validationErrorMode=CLEAN
```

For each sql migration a CRC32 checksum is calculated when the sql script is executed. The validate mechanism checks if the sql migrations in the classpath still has the same checksum as the sql migration already executed in the database.

validationErrorMode=CLEAN is exclusively intended as a convenience for development. Even tough we strongly recommend not to change migration scripts once they have been checked into SCM and run, this provides a way of dealing with this case in a smooth manner. The database will be wiped clean automatically, ensuring that the next migration will bring you back to the state checked into SCM.

This configuration can be used from API, [maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/MavenGoalMigrate) or [command line](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/CommandLine).

Comment: validationErrorMode is deprecated. Use cleanOnValidationError instead. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

With newer Flyway, you would use

```
flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
flyway.setCleanOnValidationError(true);
flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(true);
```

To drop everything if the checksum of the file changes or the version table is missing.

Comment: No need for initOnMigrate in this case. That's for existing databases only.

Comment: Yes, it is required if the schema is not empty. It will actually force to create a version table (anyway). Thats I guess a bit risky, but it is what you typically want to use for ITs.

Comment: As the question says, the db should be cleaned and remigrated after a change. If it gets cleaned, not need to call init.

Comment: This would not explain why you need "if any of those changed". Anyway, the setting is making the cleanup more aggressive, depending on your needs this is required or unneeded.